Any way to to add more than one IP at a time using "ip addr add"?
Is there any way to do this?:
ip addr add 2b00:13d8:700d:b8cf:cd8:15da:3b72:c792/64 2b00:13d8:700d:30fb:c60:a08e:225a:7073/64 2b00:13d8:700d:30fb:c60:a08e:225a:8a23/64 dev eth0

One IP works but I can't get multiple IPs to work. I want to add 20 or so specific IPv6 addresses, do I need to add one at a time? I prefer the addresses not be randomly generated. I would like to add specific IPs.

Du they all belong to the same /64 subnet?

They all belong to the same /48.

Okay, so in a sense you want to assign multiple /64 subnets to the same network card. That can be done in Linux by using sub interfaces and VLANs.

@LasseMichaelMølgaard Why would you need sub interfaces for that? You can literally add multiple addresses to a single interface, since probably kernel 2.4 or so. It's what OP is already doing.

Why do you need to add them all at a time? Why for a in addr addr addr ...; do ip addr add $a ...; done isn't enough? Why are you adding them by hand at all, what is the core problem you're attempting to solve that way?

Okay. Now we are moving into the territory of how OPs network is constructed. OP has not given any information about that part. The default way is to segment a network into sizes of /64. We only know that that they belong to same /48 subnets, which you can divide into 65536 subnets. OP has only stated that they cannot assign multiple ip addresses to the same NIC. We havent even gone to the part if said ip addresses are reachable. However OP has hinted that ip addr add did not work, so I doubt a loop over the same command would work either?

@NikitaKipriyanov I don't want to add them one by one. I want to add many specific IP addresses all at the same time. Can you elaborate on your addr addr addr ...; do ip addr add $a ...; done ? I don't fully understand that but maybe it could do the trick.

Maybe I can write a bash script that will pass a list of specific IPv6 addresses in a variable.

This is exactly the script snippet, addr addr addr ... meant to signify a list of all the addresses to add, everything else is a standard bash for loop construct: for var in list; do command; command with $var; command; done; in our case, we have a single command in the loop, ip addr add $a ...
